# How to find ideal of an algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I know that if $k$ is an algebraically closed field then $\mathcal {I}(Z(I))=\sqrt I$, where $I$ is an ideal in $k[x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n]$. But what if $k$ is not a algebraically closed field? For example if I need to find ideal of $Z(xy-1)$ or $Z(x^2+y^2-1)$, where the underlying field is $\mathbb Q$. Is there any general method for this?

$\underline{Edit}$: I just need to show that the two varieties $Z(xy-1)$ and $Z(x^2+y^2-1)$ are not isomorphic over $\mathbb Q$. For this it is enough to show that their coordinate rings are not isomorphic. But I cannot figure out their coordinate rings. Any idea how to proceed? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note $\mathbb Q[x, y] /\langle xy-1\rangle \cong \mathbb Q[x, x^{-1}]$ is a UFD, while $\mathbb Q[x, y]/\langle x^2+ y^2-1\rangle$ is not a UFD as $x^2 = (1-y)(1+y)$. (When the field is $\mathbb C$, $\mathbb C[x,y]/\langle x^2 + y^2-1\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C[x,y] /\langle xy-1\rangle$ by $(x, y)\mapsto (x+iy, x-iy)$ and thus is also a UFD).

Comment: @JohnMa I suppose in the case of $\mathbb Q$ it is extremely important to show that $x$, $(1-y)$ and $(1+y)$  are irreducibles and not associate to each other and I need to do some work to show that.