# Hartshorne exercise 1.8

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, commutative-algebra

**Question**: Let $Y$ be an affine variety of dimension $r$ in $\mathbb A^n$. Let, $H$ be a hypersurface in $\mathbb A^n$ and assume that $Y\nsubseteq H$. Then every irreducible component of $Y\cap H$ has dimension $r-1$.

**Answer**:Let, $V$ be an irreducible component of $Y\cap H$. Then, $\dim V=\dim k[x_1,\cdots ,x_n]/\mathcal{I}(V)$. Now, $V\subseteq Y\cap H\subseteq Y$. This implies, $\mathcal{I}(V)\supseteq\mathcal{I}(Y\cap H)\supseteq\mathcal{I}(Y)$.

So, 
\begin{align*}
\dim V &=\dim\frac{\frac{k[x_1,\cdots ,x_n]}{\mathcal{I}(Y)}}{\frac{\mathcal{I}(V)}{\mathcal{I}(Y)}}\\
&=\dim\frac{k[x_1\cdots ,x_n]}{\mathcal{I}(Y)}-\text{ht}\frac{\mathcal{I}(V)}{\mathcal{I}(Y)}\\
&=r-\text{ht}\frac{\mathcal{I}(V)}{\mathcal{I}(Y)}
\end{align*}
Here, $\mathcal{I}(V)/\mathcal{I}(Y)$ is a prime ideal of the finitely generated $k$ algebra $k[x_1,\cdots ,x_n]/\mathcal{I}(Y)$, which is also a domain as $V$ is a closed irreducible subset of $Y\cap H$ and hence of $X$.

$\underline{\text{Claim}}$: ht $\mathcal{I}(V)/\mathcal{I}(Y)=1$

Proof: $k[x_1,\cdots ,x_n]/\mathcal{I}(Y)=B$ is a Noetherian integral domain. Let, $H=Z(g)$ and $Y=Z(f_1,\cdots ,f_k)$. If $g\in\mathcal{I}(Y)$ then $H=Z(g)\supseteq Z(\mathcal{I}(Y))=\overline{Y}=Y$, which is a contradiction to the given hypothesis. Hence, $g\notin\mathcal{I}(Y)$. So, ($\overline{0}\neq) \overline{g}$ is not a zero divisor in the integral domain $k[x_1,\cdots ,x_n]/\mathcal{I}(Y)$. Now, $V\subseteq Z(g)$ which implies $\mathcal{I}(V)\supseteq\mathcal{I}(Z(g))=(g)$. Hence, $g\in\mathcal{I}(V)$.

If $\overline{g}$ is a unit in $B$, then $g-1\in\mathcal{I}(Y)\subseteq\mathcal{I}(V)$. But, $g\in\mathcal{I}(V)$ which implies $1\in\mathcal{I}(V)$ and this is a contradiction. So, $\overline{g}$ is not a unit in $B$.

Now, we want to show that $\mathcal{I}(V)/\mathcal{I}(Y)$ is a minimal prime ideal containing $(\overline{g})$. Any prime ideal in $B$ is of the form $\mathfrak p /\mathcal{I}(Y)$ where $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal in the polynomial ring containing $\mathcal{I}(Y)$. Now Let, $\overline{g}\in\mathfrak p /\mathcal{I}(Y)$ where $\mathfrak p /\mathcal{I}(Y)\subseteq\mathcal{I}(V)/\mathcal{I}(Y)$. Then,$g\in\mathfrak p\subseteq\mathcal{I}(V)$. This implies, $Z(\mathfrak p)\supseteq Z(\mathcal{I}(V))=V$. Now, $(g)\subseteq\mathfrak p$ and also $\mathcal{I}(Y)\subseteq \mathfrak p$. Hence, $H=Z(g)\supseteq Z(\mathfrak p)$ and $Y=Z(\mathcal{I}(Y))\supseteq Z(\mathfrak p)$. This implies, $Y\cap H\supseteq Z(\mathfrak p)$. As $Z(\mathfrak p)$ is irreducible and $V$ is an irreducible component of $Y\cap H$ and $Z(\mathfrak p)\supseteq V$, we have $Z(\mathfrak p)=V$. This implies $\mathfrak p =\mathcal{I}(Z(\mathfrak p))=\mathcal{I}(V)$. Hence, $\mathcal{I}(V)/\mathcal{I}(Y)$ is a minimal prime ideal containing $(\overline{g})$. By Krull Hauptidealsatz ht$\mathcal{I}(V)/\mathcal{I}(Y)=1$.

So, we get $\dim V=r-1$.

---

Please check my proof. Also, it will be very helpful if I get some "geometric" or any other point of view about this exercise. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know what the difference is culturally - people here are very happy to write long explanations to other peoples questions, but requests for proof checking are often frowned upon or seen with disdain. It's curious and frustrates me also. Perhaps it is because normally one gets paid for grading, and it feels too much like work. See -- I am more content to write this than I am to decipher your argument. Anyway, you use the Hauptidealsatz, so it is probably right. The geometric picture should be that chopping a sphere or parabola or plane or some other surface with a plane gives a curve.

Comment: Perhaps because it is very dangerous to say "yes" to people in a situation when it is possible that something is being miscommunicated? This exercise has certainly been answered here before, you can find an answer and compare yours to it.

Comment: @AreaMan I think it's quite simple. When people answer questions I think that 90% of the time it's because they want to 'test their knowledge' or 'assert their knowledge' (not even in a mean/condescending way--it feels good to answer questions and feel like you've accomplished something). Proof checking is the same (often times MORE) work without any of that dopamine hit. I'm not saying it's morally reasonable if the idea is that we are here 'to help others' but I think that's the reality of the situation.

Comment: This all being said, I read your argument and (unless I missed something) it seems fine. The geometric content is what's advertised on the tin. Namely, it seems patently geometrically obvious that since `dimension means number of parameters needed to define it' (intuitively of course) that looking at $f=0$ is like 'specifying one of the parameters' and thus we are only left with 1 less free parameters, and thus one less dimension. Your argument is the down-and-dirty commutative algebra needed to verify this geometrically 'obvious' idea. The reason why anything needs to be said at all

Comment: is that, a priori, the above argument works if we can extend $f$ to some system of parameters $\{f_1=f,f_2,\ldots,f_n\}$ (e.g this is true if $f$ is linear). Since we can't literally we actually have to do something.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thank you for your comments. Can you say something about [this problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936769/how-to-find-ideal-of-an-algebraic-set)?

Comment: Sorry but basing on the theory of the previous pages of Hartshorne, how can you discard the casis when $Y\cap H=\emptyset$?

Comment: @Richard [discard the casis]---> Did you mean [discard the case] ?